# Number("999") gives 999 but Number(input.value) gives NaN, even though displaying input.value gives "999" exactly what I enter in Number("999")

Tags: javascript, numbers

[Screenshot of my attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbIZb.jpg)

I am a beginner to coding. Just started JS. This is my first post on this forum too. 
Question: Please see the code. "999" is entered WITH quotation marks. First as Number("999") which displays 999 on screen. But if I enter "999" (quotes included) in an input box, then use Number() to convert value from input box, it displays NaN??? Even though when I display value from input it is "999".

Please guide.

p.s. i tried to upload screenshot, doesn't seem to show up! But url is in beginning of my post.

```
<html>
   <body>
       <p id="demo1"></p>
       <br>
       <br>
       <br>
       <input id="number" />
       <br>
       <button onclick="fn()"> Type "999" with quotes</button>
       <p id="demo2"></p>
       <p id="demo3"></p>
       <script>
           document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = Number("999");
           function fn()
           {
               var age = Number(document.getElementById("number").value);
               document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = age;
               document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = document.getElementById("number").value;

           }
       </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The value of a form control is always a string, so without quotes you're getting `Number('9999')` but when you include the quotes, you're getting `Number('"9999"')` which resolves to NaN because of the quotes. Note that in javascript, single and double quotes are interchangeable, but must be matched (e.g. you can do `'"a"'` or `"'a'"`).

Comment: Thanks! that makes sense.I had tries ' "999" ' to get NaN, but didn't occur to me that this is what was happening to value from form control too.

Answer (score 7):

When you type `999` into the input box, then the value of the input box is `"999"`. Referencing the value property will be treated the same in your code as the literal `"999"`.

When you type `"999"` into the input box, the value of the input box is `"\"999\""`.

Think about it this way: if you typed `foo bar` into the input box, the value has to be the string `"foo bar"`. The value couldn't be `foo bar`. That's not valid javascript syntax.

---

If you want to allow quotes but not require them, you could strip off all quotes with a text-replacement:

```
var age = Number(document.getElementById("number").value.replace(/"/g, ''));
```

If it's important that the quotes make sense and that the value be interpreted like a javascript string, you could use JSON.parse:

```
var age = Number(JSON.parse(document.getElementById("number").value));
```

Comment: Yes, but how would you fix this? I imagine OP cares about that more.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's the opposite: the JS literal `"999"` produces the string `999`, and the literal `"\"999\""` produces the string `"999"`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer AgentME.
It would definitely be informative to know a way around it.

Comment: @Oriol I don't think you're disagreeing with me. The literal `"\"999\""` corresponds to the input box displaying `"999"`, and the user typing `"999"` in the input box is equivalent to the literal `"\"999\""` in the code. These are just phrasing the same thing in opposite ways.

Comment: I've edited the answer to show how to accept input from the user that contains quotes. I wasn't sure if that was something you actually wanted to do, or if it was just a way to demonstrate the question about how strings work.

Comment: definitely that extra info was helpful.